# [400 CHANNEL_INVALID]: The channel parameter is invalid (caused by "channels.GetChannels")

Tags: python-3.x, linux, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyrogram

I want to deploy the File Sharing Bot Telegram on my vps linux debian 10.4 but the code is error when i run the main.py like in the log. For Bot Working Use : (pyrogram) (TgCrypto) (Pyromod) And For Database Use (sqlalchemy~=1.3.23) (psycopg2-binary) (feedparser)

the code i use https://github.com/CodeXBotz/File-Sharing-Bot

````
root@Serverdwiki:/home/dwiki/File-Sharing-Bot# python3 main.py 
Pyrogram v1.2.18, Copyright (C) 2017-2021 Dan 
Licensed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3 or later (LGPLv3+)

[16-Dec-21 16:19:43 - WARNING] - bot - [400 CHANNEL_INVALID]: The channel parameter is invalid (caused by "channels.GetChannels")
[16-Dec-21 16:19:43 - WARNING] - bot - Bot can't Export Invite link from Force Sub Channel!
[16-Dec-21 16:19:43 - WARNING] - bot - Please Double check the FORCE_SUB_CHANNEL value and Make sure Bot is Admin in channel with Invite Users via Link Permission, Current Force Sub Channel Value: -1001671790214
[16-Dec-21 16:19:43 - INFO] - bot - 
Bot Stopped. Join https://t.me/ CodeXBotzSupport for support ```
````

IF i dont fill the FORCE_SUB

The error log

```
root@Serverdwiki:/home/dwiki/File-Sharing-Bot# python3 main.py 
Pyrogram v1.2.18, Copyright (C) 2017-2021 Dan <https://github.com/delivrance>
Licensed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3 or later (LGPLv3+)

[16-Dec-21 16:24:09 - WARNING] - bot - [400 CHANNEL_INVALID]: The channel parameter is invalid (caused by "channels.GetChannels")
[16-Dec-21 16:24:09 - WARNING] - bot - Make Sure bot is Admin in DB Channel, and Double check the CHANNEL_ID Value, Current Value -1001671790214
[16-Dec-21 16:24:09 - INFO] - bot - 
Bot Stopped. Join https://t.me/CodeXBotzSupport for support
```